# Copy contents of a directory to root directory without relative path

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, osx

I have the following structure:

```
root_directory/  
          foo  
          bar/
             x/
               a.txt
               b.txt  
             y
             .a_file
           scripts/
                my_script.sh
```

I want the `my_script` to copy the contents of `bar/x` to be under the `root_directory`
If I use:
`cp -r ../bar/x ..` it will break if I run the script outside the `scripts` directory.

How can I do this so that it works for both Mac and Linux?

Comment: Use absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

Or if you prefer relative paths, you could determine the absolute path to the script's directory with the help of the `BASH_SOURCE` array variable which holds the path to the script:

```
scripts=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"; pwd)
cp -R "$scripts"/../bar/x "$scripts"/..
```

GNU's `cp` doesn't care if `-r` or `-R` is used, but the BSD man page lists `-r` as discouraged, so better use the `-R`:

> Historic versions of the `cp` utility had a `-r` option.  This implementation
>   supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
>   does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Comment: I mention without relative paths in the title

Comment: @Jim Variable `$scripts` is absolute. Run your script from outside the scripts directory and test it…

Comment: How is `$scripts/../bar/x` better than `../bar/x`? The `..` is what I wanted to avoid

Comment: The path `"$scripts"/..` always points to your root directory (parent directory of `scripts`) while `..` points to the 
parent directory from where your script was started (parent of `$PWD`). If you don't want to use `..`, then use [Nasir Riley's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546010/332764) and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is telling it to copy the contents of the directory `bar/x` that is located above the working directory as denoted by `../bar/x`. If you aren't in the `scripts` directory then it's not going to work because `bar/x` won't be located above it. In the case that you are working elsewhere in the system and there happens to be another `bar/x` located in the directory above where your are working then it will copy it but it won't be the same `bar/x` that is located above the `root_directory/scripts` directory. The only way to get it to work anywhere on the system is to use the absolute path:

```
cp -r /path/to/root_directory/bar/x /path/to/root_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want/need full paths, this is my proposal:

```
dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd -P)
cd $dir
cd ..
root=$PWD
cd bar
bar=$PWD
cp -r $bar/x $root
```

---

Get current script's full path

```
dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd -P)
```

---

Go to `dir`, then back a step, you are in the "root" dir, assign to a variable:

```
cd $dir
cd ..
root=$PWD
```

---

Got to `bar`, assign it to a variable, then use the `cp` command using the variables

```
cd bar
bar=$PWD
cp -r $bar/x $root
```

Comment: I mention without relative paths in the title

Comment: Sorry. Anyway, my answer doesn't really use relative paths. What it does, is get the full paths starting withs the script's path. So all you need is the later and nothing else. It can be helpful if you move your directory structure to another place.